# Remove specific javascript when viewing page in Customizer?

Tags: php, customization, jquery, theme-customizer

I have a javascript which reloads the page when content change is detected. This is the behaviour I want on the main site. But when I use the Wordpress Customizer I don't want this behaviour as it makes it very hard to work and Customize the page (the page tries to reload).

I tried deregistering the script and create a copy of the script without the reload function.
This is how I did it:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'customize_enqueue_appc_js' );
function customize_enqueue_appc_js() {
   if ( is_customize_preview() ) {
        wp_deregister_script( 'app-js' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'appc-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascripts/appc.js', array('jquery'), false, true );
   }
}
```

My idea here is to detect if you are on customizer with `if ( is_customize_preview() ) {` and if true, deregister the javascript called `app-js`, and enqueue the script `appc-js` which hasn't got the reload function.

But this doesn't seem to work. Is it because the Customizer views the page without modifications? Are you able to do something like this? Modifying the page functions when viewed in Customizer?

Is there any other approach to this? Like doing this in jQuery?

Comment: What you've done should work. How is the original script enqueued? Make sure your hook that deregisters the script runs _after_ it's been registered by running it at a later priority.

Comment: The priority might be the problem! I just changed it to `999` and it seems to work. Will be doing some testing! Thank you @JacobPeattie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add_action have 4 parameters, the third one being priority ($priority). Usually plugins and child themes load their scripts after a parent theme to ensure that it doesn't get overrun later on. So it is wise and good practice to run your action dead last. To to this, you will need a very low priority, ie very high number.

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery_loadup', 999 );